# How to get national holidays in using Microsoft-graph API

Tags: java, android, microsoft-graph-api

I can't find Outlook national holidays calendar data API. How to get national holidays using Outlook Calendar or Event API?

I want to use this API in Android.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is no method for pulling a list of national holidays from Microsoft Graph API.